# Finding $\frac{d}{dx}(\log(x))^2$ by definition.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, derivatives

Finding $\displaystyle\frac{d}{dx}(\log(x))^2$ by definition.

$\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx} (\log(x))^2 = \displaystyle\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(\log(x+h))^2-(\log(x))^2}{h}$

I tried multiplicating up and down by $(\log(x+h))^2+(\log(x))^2$, but all I got was a tautology...

What can I do?

Comment: Make sure it is clear where your squared sign is. Are you trying to find the derivative of $\log(x)^2$ or the second derivative of $\log(x)$? It is unclear because your squared sign is outside the brackets.

Comment: I would start with the fact that $\log(x+h)=\log(x)+\log\left(1+\frac{h}{x}\right)$. From there, expand and cancel the logarithms and look at what remains.

Comment: @Landuros: it seems pretty clear that he means to find the derivative of the square of the logarithm. He wrote out the definition correctly, even.

Comment: @Clayton Yes, it's what I suspected. Use log laws to see that $\frac{d}{dx}(\log (x)^2) = 2\frac{d}{dx}(\log(x))$

Comment: @Landuros I mean the derivative of $\log(x) \times \log(x)$

Comment: @Landuros get with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}\left[\log^2 x\right]
&= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\log^2(x+h) - \log^2 x}{h} \\
&= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(\log(x+h) - \log x)(\log(x+h) + \log x)}{h} \\
&= \lim_{h \to 0} \bigl(\log (x+h) + \log x\bigr) \; \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\log(x+h) - \log x}{h} \\
&= 2 \log x \; \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h} \log\left( 1 + \frac{h}{x} \right) \\
&= 2 \log x \; \lim_{h \to 0} \log \left(1 + \frac{h}{x}\right)^{1/h} \\
&= 2 \log x \; \log \lim_{h \to 0} \left(1 + \frac{1}{x} \cdot h\right)^{1/h} \\
&= 2 \log x \; \log e^{1/x} \\
&= \frac{2 \log x}{x}. 
\end{align*}$$